# Hazelcast: destroy dynamically created but unconfigured replicated map (hazelcast 4.0.0)

Tags: hazelcast

in our cluster of 4 application servers (all of which use embedded hazelcast) we experimented with dynamically replicated maps. After a implementation error, we ended up having replicated maps with about 1g of memory consumption which we wanted to discard.
We created new distributed maps in our dynamic configuration and made an rolling update to the cluster.

The current state is now, that the old replicated maps are still active and consuming memory and hazelcastInstance.getDistrubutedObject("...").destroy() does not remove the map from all cluster members.

Also, asking the distributedObjects for their service type or size returns "null".

Is there a way to destroy unconfigured distributed objects from our cluster?

```
distributedObject.name == null
DistributedObjectUtil.getName(distributedObject) == "Some Name"
distributedObject.serviceName == null
distributedObject.getClass() == com.hazelcast.map.impl.proxy.MapProxyImpl.class
distributedObject.size() == null (!!)
distributedObject.keySet() == null
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

My bad: destroy() needed some time to remove the elements from all cluster members. After a few minutes, the distributed objects where gone.